# Wordpress transfer to live web server on subdomain only loading wp_header element

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I have migrated my local wordpress site to a subdomain on a live web server and only the header element has loaded. I am not getting any output in the console despite having debugging mode set to true.

I have a custom nav element that is called at the end of the header which I have written the get_nav() and wp_nav() functions into my general-template.php file like so:

```
function get_nav( $name = null) {

    do_action('get_nav', $name);

    $templates = array();
    $name = (string) $name;
    if ( '' !== $name ) {
        $templates[] = "nav-{$name}.php";
    }

    $templates[] = 'nav.php';

    locate_template( $templates, true );
}

function wp_nav(){
    do_action('wp_nav');
}
```

the top of my index.php looks like this:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>

       <div class="row justify-content-end icon-post-container">
         <div class="icon-featured-image">
            ....
```

and the top of my header.php looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<p><?php get_categories(); ?></p>
<div class="container-fluid main-container">
....
```

with the end of the header.php file:

```
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
    <?php get_nav();?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

all of the site functionality works on localhost and there seems to be no errors with loading the custom style sheets, bootstrap files and fontawesome js and css on the live server.

this is my first time working with Wordpress and would appreciate if anyone can help narrow down why the header element is the only php file that is loading.

Comment: please attach a screenshot of what it is loading in front end

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/h2qYEqQ - I can't show the actual page for privacy reasons. There is a default wordpress navigation loading however I have that set to display: none; as I have created my own navigation - this is not visible in the screen shot

Comment: it seems you missed some php tag or some syntax in your code inside your body, so it is not displaying

Comment: wouldn't the error be printed on the page if there was some kind of syntax error? I have run into syntax issues before and they were printed in the divs/elements where the error were occurring. I am not versed in PHP so I don't fully understand how the code reacts to these errors. Does the interpreter just throw an error and stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

The general-template.php file was not overwriting during the push to the live server. No problems with the code, just an old version of the file.